# Looping through Drawable resources?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-resources

I want to loop through ten Drawable resources named ab1, ab2 ab3,ab4,ab5 etc. and call a function on them.

```
  b = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab1, reqHeight, reqWidth);
```

i am looking for something like this.

```
 for(int i =1; i<11; i++)
 {
     b = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab[j], reqHeight, reqWidth);
  }
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Are ab1, ab2, etc. members of R.drawable? Why aren't you keeping them in a collection/array ?

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put those objects in list

```
list.add(R.drawable.ab1);
list.add(R.drawable.ab2);
list.add(R.drawable.ab3);
list.add(R.drawable.ab4);
.
.
.
```

and then you can iterate through that list, using `list.get(i)` and pass each object in the method.

```
for(int i =1; i<11; i++)
 {
     b = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),list.get(i), reqHeight, reqWidth);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not well experienced in android but in Java SE I put every object in a java.util.Vector and iterate over the vector elements.

Maybe some like this

```
for(int i =1; i<11; i++) {
b = someMethod(getResources(), vectorDrawables.elementAt(i), reqHeight, reqWidth);
}
```

I just cant remember how to add a GUI element to a vector.